# React native render from array.map sometimes messes up order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Yeyy, finally my first question on stackoverflow! Any help much appreciated! I am not allowed to add images to the post (yet), so they're linked to the post.

**Task:**

1. I have an array of objects which contain info on how to render a text. For example:
   [{"type":"in","style":"font-size:40px;","content":"Sehr geehrte","key":"pos_0"},{"type":"ts","style":"font-size:40px;","content":" ","key":"s0"},{"type":"in","style":"font-size:40px;","content":"Damen und Herren","key":"pos_1"},{"type":"ts","style":"font-size:40px;","content":",","key":"pos_2"}...]
2. Some of the parts are supposed to be rendered as normal Text.
3. Some of the parts are supposed to be rendered as TextInput.
4. The text is rerendered within the same screen after button click (whereby a formely visible field might turn into an TextInput).

**Problem:**
It works in 90% of all cases, which looks like this:
[correctly rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6nEd.jpg)
BUT in ~10% it messes up by squeezing some of the TextInput at the beginning of the ScrollView and leaving gaps where they belong, which looks like that:
[mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gniWI.jpg)

**The Code:**
(within a ScrollView the function renderTextForNative is called, which returns an array)

*ScrollView:*

```
<ScrollView>
          {(()=>{
            switch(st.phase){
              case "uninit":
                return(st.displayText?(<View><Text>{renderForNative(st.displayText)}</Text></View>):(<Text></Text>))
              case "memorizeAndRecall":
              case "eval":
              case "fineval":
                const rendered = renderTextForNative(st.displayText, setState)
                return(<View><Text>{rendered}</Text></View>)
            }
          })()}
      </ScrollView>
```

*Function renderTextForNative*

```
const renderTextForNative = (renderThis, statecb) => {
  const res=  renderThis.map((ele) => {
    ...
    if(ele.type==="ts"){
      return (<Text key={ele.key} style={ele.style}>{ele.content}</Text>)
    } else if(ele.type==="in"){
      return (<View key={ele.key}><TextInput autoFocus={autofocus} onChangeText={(t)=>{let act={type:"doInput", key:ele.key, newValue:t}; statecb(act)}} style={{borderWidth:1,color:"#000000",textAlign:"center",height: 20, width: conWidth }}/></View>)
    }else if(ele.type==="inco"){
      ...
            </View>)
          }
      }
    )
    return res
   }
```

**What I tried:**

- I made sure the key property for every element stays the same, and it is the same for correct renderings and messy renderings.
- the same applies for the order of elements in the array.
- I did try to find similar questions here, but to no avail.

It would be great if somebody had a solution or could point me in the right direction!

Comment: instead of for loop you can try flatlist by the react-native team it self . it is optimised to fulfill all the mobile cases.

Comment: Thanks, will try it